# Specifying the range of supported Rails versions in a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, version

The `config/environment.rb` of my rails project contains this line:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '>= 2.3.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Which makes sure that only Rails of version 2.3.2 or greater will be used to run this app.

Is there a way of specifying both the lower and the upper boundary at the same time? So that it would run, say, only on versions higher than 2.3.1 and lower than 2.3.6?

Answer (score 0):

I dug around in Rails and Rubygems source for about an hour, and I'm sorry but I can't say exept to give it a go! Install a few rails versions and then see what happens!

Comment: Well, that's what I did prior to asking the question. But thanks.

Comment: Thanks for having a decent try yourself first then. You might find somehting somewhere in here: http://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/source_index.rb Especial the search method.